# Paperclip upload to S3 on Heroku stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

Somewhere between April 10 and yesterday, image upload to Amazon S3 using Paperclip appears to be broken for our Rails application on Heroku. I get the following message:

```
A AWS::S3::Errors::RequestTimeout occurred in topics#update:
 Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.
 vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/core/client.rb:277:in `return_or_raise'
```

I looked through our code changes in the past 10 days to see if we changed anything close to the Paperclip code or Gemfile, but I haven't found anything. The [Heroku status page](https://status.heroku.com/) doesn't report anything broken, nor does the [Amazon S3 status page](http://status.aws.amazon.com/).

Does anyone know any changes to Heroku, S3 or the interaction between them that could somehow be related to this? Or very subtle, seemingly unrelated, things that could have broken our setup?

The application runs on a Cedar stack on Heroku, using Rails 3.2.1, Paperclip 3.0.1, aws-s3 0.6.2 and aws-sdk 1.3.9.  Our Gemfile.lock is [here](https://gist.github.com/2384124).

Answer (score 4):

`bundle update` did the trick. The Paperclip, Aws and Heroku gems have all had a minor update recently.